# How to count the number of elements that match a condition with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, count

I've tried a lot of things but the most logical one for me seems this one:

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Take(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked).Count();
```

`AllMyControls` is a Collection of `UserControls`, what I want to know is how many `UserControls` have the `IsActiveUserControlChecked` property set to true.

What I get in VS is:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type
```

What's wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Where(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked).Count()
```

or simply

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Count(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked);
```

Since you are a beginner, it would be worthwhile to take a look at [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation

Comment: Even simpler :D `int divisor = AllMyControls.Count(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked);`

Comment: @keyboardP I added this to the answer before your comment, but thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 8):

Why not directly use `Count`? That `== true` statement is also highly redundant.

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Count(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked);
```

Also, you are getting an error on your [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062.aspx) method because it is waiting for an `int`. You need to specify the number of contiguous elements from the start of the collection you want to get, you cannot put a lambda expression. You need to use [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534804.aspx) for that. So

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.TakeWhile(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked == true).Count();
```

would have been correct, but would not work the way you expect it; it stops once the condition is broken. So if AllMyControls contains `true, true, false, true`, `TakeWhile` with `Count` will return 2 instead of your expected 3.

Comment: Yes, actually in my code it has to be !=true, and I like that for clarity. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Sturm Oh, then you can write `!p.IsActiveUserControlChecked` instead of `!= true` or `== false`

Answer (score 1):

Do not [KISS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple)

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Count(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for `Take` requres an `int` and you are passing in a delegate/ lambda expression. Take is designed to just take the first `count` of the elements.

You can use the `Count` method and pass in a delegate to count the elements that fit its criteria.  This way you only iterate the IEnumerable once, rather than first culling out the ones that don't fit your criteria, and then again to actually count them.

```
AllMyControls.Count(p => p.IsActiveUserControlChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int divisor = AllMyControls.Where(x => x.IsActiveUserControlChecked == true).Count();
```