# Count elements that match a condition with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried to use the code from [How to count the number of elements that match a condition with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244039/how-to-count-the-number-of-elements-that-match-a-condition-with-linq) 
It works but I always have the result equal to a quantity of elements in my list. There are 10 dates on my list and get 10 as the result. I need to count elements with a certain date.

```
var zz = both.ToList(); // dates list
int con = list1.Where(p => list1.Contains(zz[0])).Count();
Console.WriteLine("count: " + con);
```

Answer (score 3):

you're using `list` twice within your code both as the source of the `Where` clause as well as the source for the `Contains` method hence it gives unexpected results. rather it should be:

```
int con = list1.Where(p => zz.Contains(p)).Count();
```

instead of:

```
int con = list1.Where(p => list1.Contains(zz[0])).Count();
```

Comment: This code works ok. Thx a lot! But why you don't you use zz[0]? How can i understand which date is used for comparison? If put the index, i am getting an error:                       Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload

Comment: @DiegoSlinger when you use `zz[0]` you're always checking of `list1` contains the first element of the list `zz` which could as well be what you want but according to your description that's very unlikely. but when you do  `Where(p => zz.Contains(p))` you're checking if each element of the source collect `list1` is contained in the list `zz` then retain that element for reduction when `Count` is called. However, if you want to specify a date instead of using contains you can do `list1.Where(p => p >= startDate && p <= endDate).Count();`. where `startDate` and `endDate` are the bounds.

Comment: Yah, now I understand. Is there any other way how can I perform the same check but only for the first element from zz list?

Comment: @DiegoSlinger just do `int con = list1.Where(p => p == zz[0]).Count();` or if you want to disregard the time portion then do `int con = list1.Where(p => p.Date == zz[0].Date).Count();`

Comment: I did like this: list1.Where(p => p == zz[0]).Count(); Works great! Please receive my respect!

Comment: @DiegoSlinger you can say thanks by accepting the answer -;)

Comment: I'd add that you can use just `Count` instead of `Where(...).Count()`, it takes a predicate.