# how to use linq for foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How do I use LINQ instead of this code?

```
 foreach (var shape in Vms_Drawing.Shapes)
        {
            if(shape.ShapeType == "Vms_Rectangle")
            {
                LocalCount++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using linq [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count)

```
int LocalCount = Vms_Drawing.Shapes.Count(shape => shape.ShapeType == "Vms_Rectangle");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Count:

```
LocalCount += Vms_Drawing.Shapes.Count(shape => shape.ShapeType == "Vms_Rectangle");
```

Note that it's not entirely clear what `LocalCount` is, and this answer differs in the use of `+=` to behave in the same manner as your question code (i.e. `LocalCount` may be non-zero before this statement).

Answer (score 0):

From Approved answer and fastest one for solution

```
int MatchedItemCount = AllMyControls.Where(obj => obj.ShapeType == "Vms_Rectangle").Count();
```

Reference Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244064/5859743

Comment: Please check now