# foreach Certain item is in a ListBox - Winform, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, listbox

I would like to know how I could find the amount of times a certain item appears in a listbox

```
foreach (string Item in listBox1.Items) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("1 Item");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Unfortunately, that cycles through the entire listBox. I only want a certain Item.

Comment: Just `Console.WriteLine(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Count(x => x == "1 Item"));` if the list items are of string type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of elements that match a condition with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244039/how-to-count-the-number-of-elements-that-match-a-condition-with-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `listBox1.Items : List<string> or string[]` ...

**Option 1:**  `listBox1.Items.Count(item => item == "YourCertainItem");`

You could use Linq

**Option 2:**  `listBox1.Items.Where(item => item == "YourCertainItem").Count();`

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the type of data you have bound to the ListBox and the types unique identifer (or the property you want to use for comparison).

For example, if you have bound a list of String to the Listbox, you could use

```
var result = listBox.Items.OfType<String>().Count(x=>x == valueToSearch);
```

Instead, if you have bound a Collection of Person Types to the ListBox, where Person.Id is the property you want to use for comparison, you could use

```
var result = listBox1.Items.OfType<Person>().Count(x=>x.Id == personToSearch.Id);
```

You need to begin by defining what would be the property you would compare the items in the ListBox by, after which you could use Linq as shown in the examples above.